# Reference Request: Categorical/Functorial approach to Formal Schemes and Formal Groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, formal-schemes

For my Bachelor thesis, I am looking for refernces about Formal Schemes and Formal Groups from the categorical point of view. So far I was only able to find Strickland's article [Formal Schemes and Formal Groups](https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/st-fsfg.pdf) which I find not really reader friendly. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Neil’s is one of the few systematic accounts of the theory that sticks rigidly to the functor of points perspective. Some less systematic or less rigid but still very useful sources include: Lazard’s _Commutative Formal Groups_, Fröhlich’s _Formal Groups_, Demazure’s _Lectures on p-divisible groups_, Demazure and Gabriel’s _Groupes Algebriques_, the discussion of formal schemes in EGA, … . Depending on your needs, you might also try to seek out a reference that’s more domain-specific; there are sources that cater more towards homotopy theorists, to arithmetic geometers, … .

Comment: Also, none of the sources above (save, perhaps, EGA) give much service to the non-affine case.